# How to properly increase the limit/point settings for Sandbox Solutions?

Tags: 2013, development, sandbox-solution

I have a SharePoint 2013 event receiver in Visual Studio. The solution does some processing of XML files (without getting in to too much detail). I am having an issue with the event receiver timing out or being terminate when it runs too long (i.e. grater than 30-40 seconds). I've read all the documentation on Resource Usage Limits on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615462.aspx). So far, I've increased the CPUExecutionTime to 3600 seconds and the WorkerProcessExecutionTimeout to 3601 -

I read that CPUExecutionTime needed to be lower than WorkerProcessExecutionTimeout. My event receiver still seems to just die out and never finish - I know this because I have logging in the code that writes to an SP List. I haven't started playing with any other AbsoluteLimits or ResourcesPerPoint. Can someone share with me how I can hike up these usage settings to allow for my solution to run for upwards of 30 minutes (if it had to)?

And as an FYI, I am stopping/starting the Sandbox service in central admin each time I'm testing/changing the limits. Lastly, I wanted to confirm that I am being forced to use sandbox solutions due to a mandate from the SharePoint Admins. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I've also hiked up the SharePointDatabaseQueryCount and SharePointDatabaseQueryTime to 500. Still no luck.